# How to create network with 3 guest virtual machines in macOS on an M1 MacBook?

Tags: networking, macos, virtual-machine, qemu

I have MacBook (M1) and I need to create 3 Virtual Machines in same network:

- pfSense firewall (x86, with 2 network adapters: WAN shared network with host and LAN network adapter as gateway for guests, DHCP on LAN network adapter)
- Kali Linux (arm64, 1 network adapter in LAN)
- Metasploitable (x86, 1 network adapter in LAN)

So I use the [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app) application because it support x86 guest machines on M1 Macs.

UTM uses QEMU to run guest virtual machines.

I tried configure QEMU flags to build network, but it isn’t working:

```
-netdev socket,mcast=230.0.0.1:1234 # not working (VMs starting but unreachable)
-netdev socket,connect/listen       # working just for 2 guests
-netdev vde                         # QEMU in UTM compiled without VDE support
-netdev tap                         # not supported on MacOS as I know
```

Is there any way to build one network with 3 guests?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do that with these per-VM settings:

For VM1:

```
-netdev vmnet-host,id=vm1,net-uuid=8493bb04-56aa-4ec0-a937-605ac1a8bd07
```

For VM2:

```
-netdev vmnet-host,id=vm2,net-uuid=8493bb04-56aa-4ec0-a937-605ac1a8bd07
```

For VM3:

```
-netdev vmnet-host,id=vm3,net-uuid=8493bb04-56aa-4ec0-a937-605ac1a8bd07
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).